# JQuery Password Validation affected to all input type password?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 inputs on the HTML form: Old password, New password, and Retype New password. I use JQuery Password Validation plugin  for New password field. But If three inputs were type of password, the plugin affected all three inputs. I want that it affect only one input (New password), how can I do that? The following is my code:

```
    // The following code is in an UserControl, the form is in the page containt this control
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // This script is for validation
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(CheckValidationStatus);
            function CheckValidationStatus(sender, args) { { var isValid = $("form").validate().form(); args.set_cancel(!isValid); } }
        </script>

    <table class="listing form" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><strong>Old password:</strong></td>
            <td class="last ofield">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOldPassword" runat="server" CssClass="text required"  TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="bg">
            <td class="first" width="172"><strong>New password:</strong></td> 
            <td class="last pwdfield">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="tNewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="text password"  TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
                 <span>Password strength</span>
                 <div class="password-meter">
                     <div class="password-meter-message">Quá ng?n</div>
                     <div class="password-meter-bg">
                         <div class="password-meter-bar"></div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="first"><strong>Retype Password:</strong></td>
            <td class="last ofield"><asp:TextBox ID="txtRetypePassword" runat="server" CssClass="text" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<p style="text-align:right">
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" />
</p>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What is your code look like? Which jquery selector is used?

Comment: Please see my code above

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the password validation plugin adds a new validation method called "password".

```
$.validator.addMethod("password", function(value, element, usernameField) {
```

One of the ways the jQuery validation plugin determines what validation methods it should call is by checking if the method name is equal to the fields type. In this case the type of all your elements are password (set by TextMode="Password"), same as the new method that was added.

The work around is to change the method name in the password validation plugin to something else.

```
$.validator.addMethod("passwordstrength", function(value, element, usernameField) {
```

You also have to change when the method is registered with the validation plugin to the new method name.

```
$.validator.classRuleSettings.password = { passwordstrength: true };
```

Now only fields that have the password class will be validated.

Comment: Thank you! This has been the bane of my life for a couple of weeks!

Answer (score 1):

Add id to your "New password" field (id="newpassword") and specify this id for jQuery Password Validation plugin.

Something like this:

`$("#newpassword").validate();`

Comment: Dont know how to apply because of something. Please see my code (updated above).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the plugin, but I think you can easily change it to apply validation only on your specific input (assign to it a unique id). Or better you can pass the ID of your new password input to the plugin and make it validate only that input.